# iPhone mail app like search on android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

My requirement is to search a list based on option criteria. When user clicked on search field a view will be appeared with some options under the search box similar to iphone mail app.  My main focus is on UI part.  Can someone help me regarding this?

Before focus on search box
[image: Before focus on search box]

After focus on search box
[image: After focus on search box]

Answer (score 0):

Yes its simply easy to implement "Search" textbox based on the button click.

**Step 1:** Take EditText and set hint as "Search All mail" and make visibility as "Gone" initially. Put it above ListView.

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/txtSearch"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:hint="Search All mail"
  android:visibility="gone"/>
```

**Step 2:** Make EditText's visibility as Visible on the button click.

Comment: Why search box initially "Gone"? My main focus is on how to design remaining part after focusing on search box. How it will append/disappear under search box?

Comment: I want to make it like iphone mail app.